# JAVA: How to get the name of file which is currently opened in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have developed an executor (jar file) for my automation framework, this executor connects to a remote machine and executes my script written in eclipse and gets the results back to my local machine. Right now I have to mention the name of file and it's path before I trigger the executor in eclipse using <kbd>Ctrl+F11</kbd>

Modification:

I want it to run the script which is open in eclipse when I run my executor using <kbd>Ctrl+F11</kbd>, e.g. I open `myscript.txt` in eclipse and hit run and it should execute `myscript.txt`.

For this I would need the name of file which is currently open in eclipse.

*NOTE:* 
I have not developed a plugin it is just a simple core Java code.

I have tried the below code:

```
if(PlatformUI.isWorkbenchRunning()) {
    IWorkbenchPage activePage = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
    String name = activePage.getActiveEditor().getEditorInput().getName();
    System.out.println(name);
}
else
    System.out.println("Work Bench Does not exist");
```

But it always returns me that `Work Bench does not exist`.

I am new to it, please let me know if something does not make sense here.

-Thanks in advance

Comment: do you run your application via a run configuration or an external run configuration?

Comment: via eclipse, i.e. run configurations

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690138/how-to-get-the-filename-of-the-current-active-tab-from-eclipse-ide

Comment: You must write an Eclipse plugin to run this code.

Comment: oh this is what I was doubting @greg-449 !,

Comment: @DurgeshPatel i have tried it, but looks like the code does not work until we use it in a plugin..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run an application via a run configuration Eclipse starts an own javaw process for that. Therefore you cannot access the environment of Eclipse from inside that process in the way you tried.

There might be a simpler solution to your problem:

1. Make your application expect the opened file to be passed as commandline argument to its main method.
2. Enter `${resource_loc}` in the "program arguments" section of the run configuration. `${resource_loc}` translates into the absolute file system path of the selected resource.

Comment: wow..!! awesome!! that just works perfect to my requirement..!! Thanks a ton